# Blur effect on multiple stacked div elements

Tags: html, css, background, blur

When using the blur filter as a backdrop-filter for multiple stacked  elements, I am encountering element separation issues as depicted in the screenshot. Here is my current CSS code:

`background-color: rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.25); backdrop-filter: blur(6px);`

It's possible that I am not utilizing the blur filter as a background filter correctly. I'm seeking advice on how to achieve a blurred effect on these elements without the undesirable separation. Is there a proper way to apply the blur to these elements and avoid this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text in a single div and use background and blur on the parent div.

Comment: Thank you, infortunately I have to use this on a page builder and can't wrap it. 

can you explain to me why backdrop-filter: blur does not work coherently when applied to multiple divs?

Comment: It is as it is. we have to handle this on our end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).